# Regex test should return true only when pattern matches throughout the string. Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I really didn't how to put it in a form of question, but I have to write a function that matches a string for a pattern `+a+`.

the string should be of format where each alphabet is surrounded by "+" sign.

I came up with this expression, `var letter = /\+\w\+/;`. The problem with this is that it returns true even if the pattern matches just once throughout the string.

for example, it returns true for `"+f+++a+b+c++"`, but it returns true for `"+f=++a+b+c++"` also.

Thank You

Comment: @gurvinder372 pattern actually seems correct - `/^(\+\w\+)+$/`. Ayush, please try it. Hm, maybe you need just `/^\+\w\+$/`? Please provide example valid/invalid strings.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew true, proposed another solution. `/^(\+\w\+)+$/` may not match if two alphabets are not separated by multiple `+`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I tried it is not working. valid string would be "+f+++a+b+c++" and invalid string would be "+f=++a+b+c++".

Comment: Try `if (/^\++(?:\w\++)+$/.test(str)) { alert("valid"); }`. The answer below would not work if you get `"+f?++a+b+c++"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can match the reverse and throw the error

Something like

```
"+f+++a=+b+=c++".match(/(\w=|=\w)/g) == null ; //false
```

and

```
"+f+++a+b+c++".match(/(\w=|=\w)/g) == null ; //true
```

Above answer only checks for `=` as the character which can separate a character, try this to for the rest

```
"f+++a+b+c++".match(/(\w[^+]|[^+]\w)/g) == null ; //true
```

and

```
"+f+++.a+b+c++".match(/(\w[^+]|[^+]\w)/g) == null ; //false
```

For a boundary case when first character is not `+` try also

```
var word = "+f+++a+b+c++";
!word[0].match(/\w/) && word.match(/(\w[^+]|[^+]\w)/g) == null ; //true
```

and

```
var word = "+f+++.a+b+c++";
!word[0].match(/\w/) && word.match(/(\w[^+]|[^+]\w)/g) == null ; //false
```

Comment: Well, `/(\w=|=\w)/g` is not likely to solve the issue. `/(^|[^+])\w|\w(?!\+)/` can help I guess if you want to follow this approach. See the comment above, `+f+++a+b+c++`  is valid, so, your initial pattern requires a little adjustment.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew OP's requirement is `each alphabet is surrounded by "+" sign.` I am checking for opposite and comparing with null. I don't think it is fair on my part to propose a solution which I have not thought about :)

Comment: I guess your `/^(\+\w\+)+$/` will work if you add quantifiers where necessary and perhaps regroup it a bit :)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew let me think on this further, as of now I am not able to see which scenario is not working with this solution.

Comment: Hi, this worked. Thank you. I am new to regex, can you explain the role "|" plays in the expression? 

Thank You

Comment: @AyushBahuguna It is  `or` between two expression it is separating. More on it here https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Using_special_characters

Comment: @gurvinder372 Hi, I've run into some problem, it returns true for `"f++a+b+"` also.

Comment: @AyushBahuguna oh, check the edits now, have considered more scenarios now.

Comment: @gurvinder372 is there a way to combine all these conditions into one? I am writing a function, which would test against examples.

Comment: In that case you can convert this to a function and do your testing